# Can I build x64 app on a 32 bit machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

How do I develop a 64bit app on a 32 bit PC?

I'm using VS 2008 on WinXP 32 bit. I set the visual studio linker to /machine:x64 and created x64 configurations. All will compile and link OK, but when I run the dependency walker on the exe I see the 64 bit mscvr90.dll, etc. pointing to all the Win32 dlls, Kernel32.dll, Advapi32, Comdlg32, Gdi32, etc.

When I copy the exe over to run on a Win64 system it is rejected "...application configuration is incorrect". How do I tell visual studio to stay away from the 32 bit realm?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called cross-compiling.

http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2007/09/08/updated-windows-sdk-visual-c-cross-compilers.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. More info:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bd2a6171-e2d6-4230-b809-9a8d7548c1b6&displaylang=en) - make sure you have it
- [Installing Visual Studio 64-bit Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588.aspx) at MSDN
- [64-bit Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx) at MSDN
- [Compiling 64-bit applications in Visual Studio 2005](http://winprogger.com/blog/?p=17)

Comment: None of those links seem relevant for native (mscvr90.dll) runtime problems, and the poster already has the cross-compiling part sorted out?

Comment: @snemarch, you think he is not missing some 64-bit components?

Comment: As noted in my answer, I think he's missing the VS2008 native redist, not the CLR :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with "rejected" executable is probably that you lack a correct manifest file, and/or that the vc2008 runtimes haven't been (properly) installed on the system. You probably need [this runtime package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bd2a6171-e2d6-4230-b809-9a8d7548c1b6&displaylang=en) (VS2008 **native** redistributables, x64 version) on the target system, if not using a .msi based install.

Even in 64bit windows, the DLLs still have their 32bit names (which imho was a bad choice, since it obviously confuses people). 32bit applications will by default have %systemroot%\system32 redirected to %systemroot%\syswow64 (where the 32bit DLLs reside), whereas 64bit applications won't get redirected. Registry access by 32bit applications also has some redirection involved. Both can be disabled per-thread with Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(), but obviously doesn't let 32bit applications load 64bit DLLs.

Comment: just curious, why did you think it was a bad choice? Is it because it's hard to tell if the file you are looking is 32 or 64 bit without running it or using a tool to inspect the file, or other?

Comment: John> yep, that's part of the reason. My biggest gripe is with the redirection though, would make more sense to have a system64. Using *32.dll names for 64bit apps unfortunately does make a bit of sense (LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VS2008, you will either have to copy the redist package along with your application on to the test machine or compile the runtime as a static library within your code.